# UIButton text and image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

I have one UIButton. In that UIButton i have to show text and image. Image should be displayed after the text. Based on text i want to adjust the button frame. 
[image: Button With Text n Image]
See the image. After the text "I am a Button", i want to add a image like arrow.

```
UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NSString *name = @"I am a button";
titleButton.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
titleButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
CGSize stringSize = [name sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Cond" size:24]}];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(300, 30, stringSize.width, 30);
//frame.size.width = stringSize.width;
[titleButton setFrame:frame];
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]];
image.frame = CGRectMake(stringSize.width, 14, 20, 13);
titleButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, stringSize.width+20, 0);
[titleButton addSubview:image];
```

I written code like this. But it is not working. Anyone can make it correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to play around `imageEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets` property of UIButton. you will definitely get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to add a `UIImageView` over the `UIButton` to get this behaviour. The `UIButton` has itself has some properties. Set the orange image as the `background image` of the `button`, set the arrow image as the `image` of the `button`. Then adjust the `insets` of the `title` and the `image` of the `button` to move the title to the left and the arrow image to the right.

```
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange_bg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -60, 0)];
[btn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 125, 0)];
```

You have to adjust the insets according to your image and button sizes.

Comment: Thanks @Suresh my text will change always. Based on text i want to adjust the image.

Comment: Then u have to find the size of the text by using the sizeWithFont and adjust the insets dynamically.

Comment: the above code is not working. If image is displayed text wont shows